# HTML live session not loading

Tags: html, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, debugging, live

I'm trying to test my website on my android device in chrome and i can successfully launch the live session in vs code (it opens on my pc) but when i try to open it on my phone with the lan IP address and port number it's stuck loading. It doesn't give any error like if i write the wrong ip address, so clearly the connection with the live session happens to some degree, but it just doesn't load. Anybody got any recommendations what i could try?

I already changed the firewall settings and tried restarting vs code too. Neither solved the problem.